# MYSQL Trigger not working

Tags: mysql, trigger

I am trying to create the following trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_customers AFTER INSERT ON wp_usermeta
    FOR EACH ROW 
    BEGIN
            if new.wp_metakey = first_name then insert into test_customer(first_name) values (new.wp_meta_value);
    END
```

I keep getting a 1064 error that says, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresopons to your MySQL server version for the right syntaxt to use near " at line 5"

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first problem is that you don't have an `END IF;`.

The next problem (assuming that you aren't doing this and just didn't include it in the question) is that when you have a [compound statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/begin-end.html), you have to change the statement delimiter from `;` to something else so that the client will send the entire `CREATE TRIGGER` statement to the server as a single statement.

Finally, the column "first_name" probably needs to be qualified with `NEW` (assume you're referencing a column in wp_usermeta called "first_name".

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS update_customers $$
CREATE TRIGGER update_customers AFTER INSERT ON wp_usermeta
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
  IF NEW.wp_metakey = NEW.first_name THEN 
    INSERT INTO test_customer(first_name) values (NEW.wp_meta_value);
  END IF;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```